# Sharepoint Powershell update every second list item

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

What I need to do is write a Powershell script withc would update every **Second** item in list. As I see it, i need to use somethin like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourServer/
$list = $web.Lists["list name"]
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item["column1"] = "New value";
  $item["column2"] = "New value";
  $item.Update();
}
```

And add **If(itemID) % 2 =0;**

Am I right? If I am, how can i get ID of List Items.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you only need to update every second item, and you don't care about the items you are editing, (using your code) you can simply do this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourServer/
$list = $web.Lists["list name"]

$i = 0

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  if($i % 2 -eq 0)
  {
    $item["column1"] = "New value";
    $item["column2"] = "New value";
    $item.Update();
  }
  $i += 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you HAL it is what i needed.
Much simpler than i thought it would be.